# C# light way to store a big matrix of bits with fast access

Tags: c#, matrix, optimization

Let M be a 2048x2048 matrix os bits.

If I wanted to store all these bits in a matrix, it wouldn't be efficient to do

`int[,] M = new int[2048, 2048]`

because it would need 32 times the space needed for bits (2048^2 * 32bits per int).

I could do `int[,] M = new int[64, 64]` and each int would give me 32 bits (and so *32×64=2048*), so I would have a good space spending, but it is kind of ugly to get, for example, the 1033th bit of some arbitrary row, cause I would have to get the (*1033%32*) bit of the (*1033/32*) int.

My question is: is there any better (or more specific way) to have this bit matrix with optimal space spending and constant access to any M[i][j] ∈ {0,1} ?

Comment: If you write your own getter/setter the "bit" approach would be both efficient and give you constant access.  It's really not that ugly.

Comment: I would frankly start there and then *measure* and *test* and see if you need something faster.  But a fixed allocation block with a constant-time calculation for location is going to be hard to beat.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [`BitArray` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of the `BitArray` class:

```
var bitMatrix = new BitArray[2048];
for (int i = 0; i < bitMatrix.Length; i++)      
    bitMatrix[i] = new BitArray(2048);  

bitMatrix[5][12] = true;
```

Note that you access the bits via `bool` values.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I've been looking for.